# How do I do a pre-order traversal in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, compiler-errors, binary-tree, traversal

I'm attempting to write a pre-order traversal algorithm on a binary tree using the recursive method. Here's what I have:

```
void traverse(BT t) {
        if (t == null){
            return;
        }

        System.out.print(t);  
        traverse(t.left);
        traverse(t.right);
        }
```

That doesn't compile for some reason. I think the problem is with the rest of my code. Here's the entire code:

```
class ZOrep extends TreeAndRepresentation {
  private int k;
  ZOrep left;  
  ZOrep right;  
  ZOrep( int m, int[] b ) { // given sequence build tree
     super( m, b );
     N = (M-1)/2;
     k  = -1;
     t = build();
    }
  ZOrep( int n, BT t ) { // given tree build sequence
      super(n, t);
      t = build();
      traverse( t );
    }
  BT build() {
      return(a[++k] == 0 ? null : new BT( build(), build() ));
    }

  void traverse(BT t) {
    if (t == null){
        return;
    }

    System.out.print(t);  
    traverse(t.left);
    traverse(t.right);
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something when I'm building the tree (with my ZOrep method). Also here's the BT class:

```
class BT {
  BT L; BT R;
  BT( BT l, BT r ) { L = l; R = r; }
}
```

Currently my compiler says it can't find the symbol for t.left and t.right.

Answer (score 2):

When the compiler says it can't find the symbol, it means the field you're trying to reference doesn't exist.

Looking at your class `BT`, this is correct; `BT` doesn't have `left` or `right`, it has `L` and `R`. Thus, replacing

```
traverse(t.left);
traverse(t.right);
```

with

```
traverse(t.L);
traverse(t.R);
```

Will fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently my compiler says it can't find the symbol for t.left and t.right.

This is because `t` is a `BT` and it doesn't have a `left` and a `right`.

I suggest you decide what you want to call your tree node class. Is it `ZOrep` or `BT` and only use one of these or you will create confusion.

```
System.out.print(t);
```

If you want to print out a BT, you will need to add a `toString()` method to it as the default won't tell you anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

What are you passing into your transverse function? If it's a BT object, then you can't use left and right, you must use L and R. Left and right are parts of your object that extends from BT, but it looks like you're passing in a BT.

Answer (score 0):

// Java

static String tree = "";

private static void preOrder(HuffTree currentObject) {

```
    if (currentObject == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (currentObject.filling == null) tree += 1;
    else tree += 0;
    preOrder(currentObject.child0);
    preOrder(currentObject.child1);
}
```

}

// class code here

import java.util.Objects;

/**

- Huffman tree as class
  */

class HuffTree implements Comparable {

```
// element filling
Byte filling;
// element repeats
int repeats;
// zero child
HuffTree child0;
// child 1
HuffTree child1;

/**
 * constructor for tree fathers and leaves
 */
public HuffTree(Byte filling, int repeats, HuffTree child0, HuffTree child1) {
    // father filling
    this.filling = filling;
    // father repeats
    this.repeats = repeats;
    // zero child
    this.child0 = child0;
    // child 1
    this.child1 = child1;
}

/**
 * finding difference between our tree's items
 */
@Override
public int compareTo(HuffTree currentByte) {
    return currentByte.repeats - repeats;
}


/**
 * take byte code as a string by recursive three search in depth
 */
public String getCodeForByte(Byte currentByte, String wayToFather) {
    // there is 4 cases:
    if (!Objects.equals(filling, currentByte)) {
        // case 1 - zero child found
        if (child0 != null) {
            // recursive code add for zero child
            String currentWay = child0.getCodeForByte(currentByte, wayToFather + "0");
            // return temporary string
            if (currentWay != null) return currentWay;
        }
        // case 2 - child 1 found. recursive code add for child 1. return temporary string
        if (child1 != null) return child1.getCodeForByte(currentByte, wayToFather + "1");
    }
    // case 3 - correct leaf found. return correct code
    if (Objects.equals(filling, currentByte)) return wayToFather;
    // case 4 - wrong leaf found. return null
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Please may you format the code in your answer and add some explaination? Thank you